# Tapjoy Screen appears moved up

Tags: iphone, ios, tapjoy

I'm developing an App for iPhone and we are using the Tapjoy framework. All works fine except two points that I can't solve. If somebody can point me for a solution will be apreciated.

First one:
The tapjoy implements a notification that is called when a new virtual good is downloaded. We saw that when we download a virtual good the download process never finishes and remains in 100% completed. In consequence the notification never is called. This happens randomly for some packages that we uploaded to Tapjoy. To solve that we used a trick, and is that we were looking for the tapjoy code and we saw a notification that is called when the file download reaches the 100%, and we used this one instead the official. This works ok, but in the download screen appears the download process like this: Downloading 100% comleted, instead of Download complete.

Second one:
When the user pushes in the purchase button of tapjoy, we use the following call in order to load the purchase screen:

```
[TapjoyConnect showVirtualGoodsWithViewController:self];
```

Randomly this screen appears properly in full screen, but sometimes appears moved up.

Someone had the same problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We'll be releasing a new version of the SDK that will fix the notification issue soon, hopefully in a week or two.

Can you give more details about your second issue? What do you mean by the purchase button of tapjoy? 
The showVirtualGoodsWithViewController method should only ever be called when you want to display the store view. When purchasing a virtual good, all other subviews are handled by the SDK so you don't need to call that method again.

Comment: The problem is with the position of the screen loaded by showVirtualGoodsWithViewController method. Sometimes loads the screen ok, fully filling the iphone screen. But most of the times the screens appears moved up and the iphone screen is not full filled.

Comment: Have you tried just calling [TapjoyConnect showVirtualGoods]? That method adds the virtual goods view as a subview to the main window view. It should work for most cases unless you're trying to do something special with your views.